# How to deploy my OctoberCMS project from localhost to live server or free web hosting server on windows OS?

Tags: octobercms

I am a beginner of OctoberCMS . Can anyone guide me to deploy octobercms whole project to free webhosting server on Windows os?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with OctoberCMS but i have done that some time ago. Follow this steps:

- clear cache of OctoberCMS - there exist plugins for that on plugins page on OctoberCMS site if you don't have one.
- make a dump of mySQL database you are using.
- copy the folder structure and files on your system to the www root (or publichtml) of your shared host.
- recover the previous mySQL dump on shared host mySQL.
- review and adjust configurations to new environment of app.php and database.php files on config folder.

And thats all.

PS: i'm supposing that your shared host have PHP and mySQL with the requirements for OctoberCMS.

JL